# SQL Query not returning data between date range

Tags: sql

I am trying to return results between column "Date of Payment" and when I run the query below I am not getting the correct results. I get data from that column where it could be  10/1/2013..Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? I just want the rows for 2017.. TIA

Date of payment column type is a nvarchar(50)

Sample column data is like 10/31/2017...

```
SELECT     ID,  [Date of Payment]
FROM         tblData
WHERE     ([Date of Payment] BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '12/31/2017')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Change your column type to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am assuming SQL Server based on the syntax.)

Fix the `[Date of Payment]` data in your table.

```
update tblData
    set [Date of Payment] = convert(date, [Date of Payment], 101);

alter tblData
    alter column [Date of Payment] date;
```

Voila!  Your problem is fixed!

You should also change the data type to use ISO standard formats:

```
WHERE [Date of Payment] BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next code 
And avoid put spaces in field name and replace it with underscore

```
SELECT     ID,  PaymentDate
FROM         tblData
WHERE (PaymentDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-01-01', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-30', 102))
```

Comment: When I run this I get incorrect syntax near 'between'? WHERE  Between CONVERT('Date of Payment',1/1/2017,103) and CONVERT('Date of Payment',31/12/2017,103)

Comment: WHERE (PaymentDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-01-01', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-30', 102))

Comment: Tried this I get error conversion failed when converting date and or time from string WHERE ( [Date of Payment] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-01-01', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-30', 102))